# Querying ElasticSearch for all documents with a Geo Point that intersects/within an indexed Geo Shape

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have a collection of geo_shapes pulled from a shape file that I have indexed into ES. I also have a large index of documents with geo_points. I'm trying to run a query that returns all the documents that have a point within a geo_shape, but keep getting zero results returned.

I'm pretty sure the mappings are correct, because I can do a query of a specific lat/long and successfully get back the geo_shape it is in. I can also do a bounding box search of the documents with geo_points and successfully get back a list of documents that match.

Here is the mapping for my geo_shapes:

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "properties": {
            "type": "geo_shape",
            "tree": "quadtree"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the mapping for the documents with geo_points:

```
{
    "docs": {
        "location": {
            "properties": {
                "coordinates": {
                    "type": "geo_point",
                    "geohash": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the query I'm trying to run is:

```
{
    "query": "geo_shape": {
        "location": {
            "indexed_shape": {
                "id": "shape_id",
                "type": "locations",
                "index": "index_name",
                "path": "geometry"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the query against the specific index/type that contains the documents with geo_points.  If I run it against the entire index then only the geo_shape document returns.

Comment: "If I run it against the entire index then only the geo_shape document returns." Are you referring to run against the entire shapes index instead of specific pre-index shape? If yes, how would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work, the locations in your second index need to be mapped as `geo_shape` (type=Point) as well (not `geo_point`), like this:

```
{
  "locations": {
    "location": {
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "geo_shape",
          "tree": "quadtree",
          "precision": "1m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then your `geo_shape` query working on [pre-indexed shapes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#_pre_indexed_shape) will work as expected

Comment: that didn't work.  I tried mapping geo-shape to the "location" level and at the "coordinates" level.  Also, if I do that then it takes away from the ability to do  a bounding box query on the geo_point.

Comment: OK.  I got it to work.  I was confused on the query which I fixed in my original post.

Comment: @Val, what would be a good way to query points inside multiple pre-indexed shapes (eg.: querying for all points inside all shapes)?